# Fatal error: php

Tags: php

I get this error:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bnet-form\form.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bnet-form\form.php on line 4" error message.

What should I do?

[image: image here]

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: `mysql` was never a function. Maybe you meant http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php `<?php=` also is incorrect. Either `<?php echo` or `<?=`. Also don't use `md5`.

Comment: Additionally: unless you explicitly want GIF answers, don't post code as images.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing specially not using MD5(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)